# Writer's Market

Tags: editing, resources, freelance

Is *Writer's Market* a viable place for a freelance editor to find possible clients? As I understand it, the book is geared towards writers finding agents/publishers, but I've never even paged through a copy; does it have other uses? Are there similar resources that I might find helpful for my purposes?

Comment: Is this the one published by those who do Writers' Digest? In the UK the Writers' and Artists' Handbook is value for money and public libraries keep copies so you can look through it.

Comment: Your local book store or library might have copies that you can peek at.

Comment: Yes, it's published by the same company that puts out Writer's Digest.

Answer (score 2):

You may have had a chance to look at the book by now, but just in case... The books are put out by Writer's Digest and there are a series of them put out annually (Poet's Market, Writer's Market, and others). These list journals, publishers, contests, conferences, etc. and their information as they pertain to a writer trying to market his or her work. As an editor, you might find useful the section on conferences, in case there are any that provide for a range of attendees and not only writing workshops. You might find contact names at various publishers, but I can't help but think you'd be better off looking at resources that discuss the whole thing from the perspective of the publisher. Unless, I'm completely misinterpreting what you are trying to find.